# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have added a **2.45mb** jar file to my Android eclipse project and now I continue to get "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space" no matter what I do.

I have researched online, and was informed to update my eclipse.ini to increase my Java VM heapsizes. I have done this for all the values in eclipse.ini and I continue to get the build error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post the lines that you added to eclipse?

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810

-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5

-Xms512m

-Xmx512m

Comment: i too just have the entries -data @noDefault in my init: I've tried adding various code including -Xms512m -Xmx512m and -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m in various permutions with the these two lines. also there are suggestions for adding about 20 more lines of code which I've also tried. someone needs to post the COMPLETE lines of code needed in the exclipse.ini, from top to bottom, and whether any file paths in the added code have to be customized, which will be different for various configurations

Comment: I've also tried launching from command line with eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m which hasn't worked

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Modify the `-XmsAm` and `-XmxBm` paremeters in `eclipse.ini` so that they are large enough. The default is `-Xms40m` `-Xmx384m`. Try changing them both to `-Xms512m` `-Xmx512m` and restart eclipse to see if that helps. If not, continue to increase the values and restart eclipse until either one of two things happens:

1. Your build completes.
2. Eclipse won't restart because you don't have enough memory.

`eclipse.ini` is located at `/etc/eclipse.ini` in Ubuntu (assuming you installed Eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories).

For MAC please see:

> Finding eclipse.ini is a wee bit tricky. To locate it, right-click on the Eclipse Application icon and select "Show Package Contents", then double-click on the "Contents" folder and then double-click on the "MacOS" folder, the home of eclipse.ini

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=61341742

Comment: [This page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example) describes how to find eclipse.ini on mac.

Comment: In Windows it sits right alongside `eclipse.exe`, wherever you put it.

Comment: The only entries I have are 
-data
@noDefault

Please advise

Comment: @JohnnyLambada Hi Johny I have added 7mb jar File and have modified the xms variable to 1024m both. But Now I am getting this error

Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: @GauravArora - will it compile with ant? Are you using the very latest sdk? It has some improvements for dex -- you may be able to get away with compiling with ant and relying on dex to use the already-compiled dex object within eclipse. From the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) _Improved the build time by pre-dexing libraries (both JAR files and library projects)._

Comment: Could you explain the difference between xms and xmx?

Comment: The flag Xmx specifies maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while Xms is specifies the initial memory allocation pool according to [this SO answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

Comment: @Cheezmeister  this is totally useless answer, it is not solving my problem,

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes checking the .jar library in project properties also causes this problem. In that case, try the following:

```
Right click your project. 
Go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export.
Uncheck the check box against your included library. 
Press OK and run the project.
```

On doing this Eclipse will take only the classes which are needed in the code, from the jar instead of storing all the classes from the jar.

Comment: Unchecking the library from 'Order and Export' results in 'ClassNotFoundException' being thrown when a class from that library is accessed from the code. The library(s) should be exported.

Comment: Yes thats right, I am getting the Java Heap Error, when I Unchecked all the library, it executes but application is crashing on the device, please help me..

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are perfect , but you can try one more thing and that is fast and easy , 
close all your unnecessary open projects in Eclipse workspace and then Restart Eclipse .

You can also increase the -XmsAm and -XmxBm paremeters in eclipse.ini .

Comment: I face same issue, I also tried, memory size changes. But problem not resolved. Finally, I did, Project Explorer -> right click -> Maven -> update project. My problem resolved. Once i took latest checkout, I should do Maven update. But I did mistake.

Comment: @Ravi how do you solve the error, let me know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties and remove your added libraries from Java Build Path hit ok,
then again re add them. I also faced this problem.By doing this I solved this issue.

Comment: This really worked for me with eclipse ADT @AndroidHacker

Answer (score -1):

**Important addition:**

The solution didn't work on my Windows (probably memory allocation issues), but did well on a Linux on same machine. So installation of another OS would help you or Windows re-installation.

Comment: Just reinstalled My OS.. didn't work. Also replaced my motherboard just in case and bought a new harddisk, that also didn't work.