# Unable to execute dex: Java heap space Java heap space

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

I am getting Unable to execute dex: Java heap space Java heap space error while executing web driver script in Eclipse IDE. I have configured Eclipse IDE with Android SDK and AVD Manager.

I also increased the `-Xms200m` to `-Xmx512m` but it did not work.

Answer (score 34):

The accepted solution to this post worked for me:
[Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space)

The gist is: Keep increasing the Xms and Xmx values until it either works or you run out of physical memory.

E.g.:
`-XX:MaxPermSize=1536m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1536m`

Answer (score 2):

You said

> I also increased the -Xms200m to -Xmx512m

-Xms200m and -Xmx512m are two different things. Maybe you wanted to say

> from -Xms200m to -Xms512m

and

> from -Xmx200m to -Xmx512m

Comment: hey this one i am not getting clearly. can u explain briefly. where can i change -Xms512m -Xmx512m. i am getting same error. tell me about this.

Comment: You can add these options in the file named **eclipse.ini** You can find more informations here http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1):

Change -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 to

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

if your eclipse project is using java compiler 1.6. I just solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my build.gradle finally solved it for me

```
dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Comment: Where is it build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

When facing this problem I found that my `eclipse.ini` was renamed to `_eclipse.ini`, thus Eclipse was not able to find it and took to these misbehaviours.

I renamed it back to `eclipse.ini` and everything backed to work normally.