# "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: android, eclipse

I am designing an android application with eclipse. When I try to run I see this window:

[image]

The message is

> "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   GC overhead limit exceeded"

Answer (score 24):

Already asked and already solved, more than once.. BTW you should edit the eclipse.ini file and give more Virtual Memory to it!

So, for example:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

Those are my default values.. try with something like that

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Look here for more details: [Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

I also find useful when something like GC overhead problems happen this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461943/3443362
If you don't have so much RAM on your PC/laptop this last suggestion is musch more better..

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I give 6GB of RAM to eclipse yet the error is not resolved. Possibly buried but not resolved. I face this issue only with eclipse installations that have the ADT Plugin installed. I guess it's a bug on the plugin.