# Every time I click on an Android XML file in Eclipse, it loads data for all API versions

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-xml

As described in the title, every time an XML file (layout or manifest) is clicked, progress shows "Loading data for ..." - and it does it for every version of the API, 2.1 to 4.4.2.

Is there any way of stopping this behaviour. as it slows the system down a great deal ?

**Update:** I've raised an AOSP [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67084) for this.

**Update 2:** I'm pleased to say that the AOSP team have now raised the priority for a fix to 'Critical'.

**Update 3:** 8 days later and I'm ***not*** pleased to say that despite it being marked as a critical bug, it's still waiting on release 22.6.2 to provide a complete fix.

**Update 4:**  Finally 22.6.2 released and it seems to work OK. Thanks go to the authors.

Comment: Always have the Android SDK version the same as ADT to prevent unforseen errors. For example, if you use SDK v22.6.1, make sure you also upgrade to ADT v22.6.1

Comment: I'm using the old Eclipse Bundle with sdk. If set Android Sdk Path to the sdk bundle, the problem appears but if i use SDK from [USER]/AppData/Android/sdk i works as espected. (AppData Android is generated by Android Studio).

My question is, what is the reason for that behavior?.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

ADT 22.6.2 is available. Just update it and this issue disappears.

You can ckeck the general notes [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: Thanks, As I'd raised the initial bug, I had starred it for e-mail notification on every comment. The authors had commented 22.6.2 as released, so I installed it 2 hours ago (+update to 4 other packages in the SDK including 22.6.2 tools). It seems to be fixed.

Comment: I updated to latest ADT version 23 but it still loads data every time I open xml file.I have also updated my Android SDK to version 23 but still problem is not solved.Can you please comment for any solution?

Comment: @akshay7692 Does it load data and never stops?

Comment: @ joao2fast4u No, it stops after loading data but eclipse freezes for a moment when its loading.This happens every time I open XML file.

Comment: it returned back at the new ADT (23.xx), What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by switching back to [ADT 22.3](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#)

Comment: how do you downgrade the adt

Comment: This stops the incessant "loading .. etc" but with a 22.6 SDK Tools and a 22.3 ADT any project created with the wizard has no stub source code or Activity in the manifest. It does make Eclipse usable though for existing projects or ones created on the command line.