# Eclipse android: loading data for android periodically execution

Tags: android, eclipse

Today eclipse is joking me. It happent that automatically, and periodically, it starts in background some operations, like

> loading data for android [version]

how can i disable that? i don't have a high performance pc, so i need to wait that background process ending for continue my job, and it's frustrating.

Comment: [i fixed switching back to ADT 22.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297573/every-time-i-click-on-an-android-xml-file-in-eclipse-it-loads-data-for-all-api/22372812#22372812)

Comment: I raised a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297573/every-time-i-click-on-an-android-xml-file-in-eclipse-it-loads-data-for-all-api and an AOSP bug report for this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67084

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll try an answer instead.

If Eclipse is intermittently compiling / running in the background, it might be that it tries to compile the Android source codes for method(s) you're referencing in your Android project(s). One way to get around this is to create a zip-format file of the Android source codes directories, for example, zip the `android-sdk\sources\android-19` directory into a single zip file and point Eclipse to this zip file.

Repeat this step for other android source codes directories that you have downloaded via the Android SDK Manager, so you might end up with something like **android-19.zip**, **android-18.zip**, **android-17.zip**, etc.

Use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to zip the directories. It's a free software (it's released under GNU LGPL licence).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe uncheck option **"Use download cache"** helps? It located there:

> Android SDK Manager -> Tools -> Options