# Eclipse loads Android data repeatedly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm currently running Eclipse Kepler, with the Android Plugin.

I recently created a new Android Project, added a few activities and everything seemed fine until I started noticing that Eclipse, everytime I opened an existing .xml file (strings, values, mainactivity, you name it) the progress console showed that Eclipse is loading the "data for Android 4.3". I mean, literally, everytime I open a .xml document.

It's quite frustrating because it loads the same package over and over again and it can take some considerable time.

The SDK is fully updated, so is Eclipse.

Comment: Give it some time.It will be fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Every time I click on an Android XML file in Eclipse, it loads data for all API versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297573/every-time-i-click-on-an-android-xml-file-in-eclipse-it-loads-data-for-all-api)

Comment: @TalhaQ: No it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching back to ADT 22.3, just like @crino said in the possible duplicated question posted by @NickT.

Thanks to both of you.