# My SDK load repetitively when i try to start emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i click on my AVD manager to lauch emulator, Eclipse load all SDK version.
Why i am facing this issue any idea...??
I had already search on google for this but it worthless for this time.

Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: Did you update your eclipse ?

Comment: First i update my SDK then it show me Update ADT plugin to latest so i update my ADT to latest one successfully and problem started.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297573/every-time-i-click-on-an-android-xml-file-in-eclipse-it-loads-data-for-all-api) that I raised, if as I suspect, you have plugin version 22.6.1. If you look through the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67084), you will see that it's not going to be fixed until 22.6.2 plugin is released.

The workaround for me was to uninstall the ADT (i.e. just the plugin, leaving the SDK at 22.6.1) then get the plugin version 22.3.0 version from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip) and install it from the 'local archive' option in Eclipse.

I hope it won't be too long before they release 22.6.2