# ADT latest update issue (22.6.1) - Layout renders every time

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

Last few days I am facing issue regarding my eclipse ADT plugin. I did not face this kind of problem earlier.

When I open layout file, it renders every time. I must say ADT is having this bug.
How can I downgrade ADT? OR when New ADT will be released with this solution?

Let me know the procedure of downgrade of ADT or any other solution.

**UPDATE**

Update to 22.6.2. Released Today(03/26/2014)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Every time I click on an Android XML file in Eclipse, it loads data for all API versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297573/every-time-i-click-on-an-android-xml-file-in-eclipse-it-loads-data-for-all-api)

Comment: answer does not show that How can I downgrade

Comment: I have updated to version 23 but issue is still there!

Comment: I'm using the old Eclipse Bundle with sdk. If set Android Sdk Path to the sdk bundle, the problem appears but if i use SDK from [USER]/AppData/Android/sdk i works as espected. (AppData Android is generated by Android Studio).

My question is, what is the reason for that behavior?.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bug. This will be fixed in the next update i guess. Few users have reported the same.

I am not able to find the link where the bug is filed. If some one come across the same pls post the link here. I am sure i saw it being filed.

You can revert back to the old one .On Eclipse go to "Installed Softwares" > Installation History

Select the one from the list. Click Revert button.

[image]

Comment: I filed the bug at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67084. This procedure has the same effect as installing ADT 22.3 from a zip. Unfortunately this still leaves SDK Tools at 22.6.1. This does leave problems in creating new projects with the wizard, but you can at least continue with existing projects or create them on the command line.

Comment: @NickT no disagreeing with that. Hope they fix this bug soon.

Comment: I'm using the old Eclipse Bundle with sdk. If set Android Sdk Path to the sdk bundle, the problem appears but if i use SDK from [USER]/AppData/Android/sdk i works as espected. (AppData Android is generated by Android Studio).

My question is, what is the reason for that behavior?.

Thanks