# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik, dex

I am stuck with this error from last 3 hours.When I checked out latest code from SVN after that it suddenly stopped working.

**Note:**

My new project size is around 135 MB
and I m using eclipse kepler.

Also there are 3 jars in myApp/res/libs named as sqlite.jar, ksoap2.jar, rt.jar

So I googled and found [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded). And also [Blog 1](http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) and [Blog 2](http://blog.simplyadvanced.net/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded/) I have edited **eclipse.ini**

From:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

To

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

But It is still not working and getting the same error in eclipse.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe try increasing memory even more than 1024

Comment: @Vinay Lodha Thanks for ur reply but what should I do?I have 4GB RAM so should I increase size from 1024 to 2048?

Comment: Tried but dont get any solution.

Comment: If its not working with 2048 RAM then I guess it is not related to memory.. I guess I am Out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this is to remove rt.jar (there are 18635 class files) file from your project. It's a heavy jar. In JRE or J2EE/J2ME, that jar file used by default. In Android I'll not, so we have to add manually.

Comment: U r right, but what is the possible solution? Any idea?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Please explain some more clear please.. From where i have to remove rt.jar. And how to add manually. Need help...

Comment: If u have added rt.jar file than and than only u have to remove it from lib folder.

Comment: @Ravi: You remove rt.jar from the JDK. In eclipse, you go to Window --> Preferences, Java --> Installed JREs, Select JDK, click edit. You should see rt.jar as the 2nd jar file. Select and remove.

Comment: i got error java was started but return exitcode 1 any solution.

Comment: @Ram :- Can u please send full error or Screen Shot... or related link. So I can understand.

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah  I am having the same error. it is happing for only one project which has large no of classes. what am I suppose to do to remove this? I removed the file you mentioned, Still having the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the value of these parameters in Eclipse Configuration Setting file

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

make them as-

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```