# Eclipse ADT Freezes when running Android Apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using a fresh install of Eclipse Luna and ADT (just deleted and redownloaded it) and whenever I try to run ANY android project I have, eclipse starts freezing and then finally freezes at "Launching  (99%)". After about 2 minutes of this, it pops up the error "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded", and I have to force quit eclipse.

This evens happens when I create a new Android project and try to run it. This is on a macbook pro running OS 10.9.4

Can anyone help me? I am incredibly frustrated by this, I feel like every time I try to program something in Android I waste more than half my time chasing and dealing with bugs in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried to adjust/allocate the memory to Eclipse instance? http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: a quick google, have you tried these? http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded,

Comment: What did it? I got the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjusting/allocating more memory in eclipse worked.

https://www.simplified.guide/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: Still a problem in Eclipse Mars.  Fortunately, this is still the solution.