# Eclipse can't install app due to google play services lib

Tags: android

I am using airpush ad service in my app and when you see in their documentation, they ask you to add google play services lib in the app for proper running of the ads.

Now I add the lib via, right click > properties>android>add lib.

The problem is now when I try to run the app on my kitkat 4.4.4 mobile, eclipse is stuck on installing process.

Whereas when I remove the google play services  library from the app, the installation happens smoothly and the app is running perfectly just not showing any ads.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the build just hang, and eventually maybe you get an error about garbage collection failing?  You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: Hey thanks for the link, I followed the answer given there and changed `XxmaxPermsSize` to 512M and it worked...well for a while. Now the app is running with google play lib but when I try to enable proguard and now install it, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Did you add the proguard rules from the play services documentation?

Comment: Yeah, my proguard file contains airpush and google play services rules

Comment: Uninstall the app, and install again while capturing logcat during the install process as well as a subsequent run attempt.  Make note of each complaint and decide if it is relevant or just unrelated noise.

Comment: Ok, btw can we debug built the app with proguard enabled or we can only export (i.e. signed built) the app.

Comment: Adding play services often makes the stock eclipse configuration run out of memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded?lq=1 - if (**and only if**) that fixes it for you we should close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Make your enable to check box of library that you have added in the next tab.