# GC stopped working when add google play service library

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, google-play-services

My project working perfect but i need map implementation and I add google play service library. After that whenever i run project my GC stopped working and eclipsed hanged. I closed eclipse and i removed google play service library and now my project working fine.

This strange but it's really happening.  I also update my google play service library. But updated library also not working.

Two error dialog I am getting when try to run my project 
[image]

[image]

I tried it approx 3 times by removing and adding library but same problem.

EDIT : I also try this library with my previous map sample project but now its also not working.

Comment: Take a look her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: Thanks @aga, my problem solved by increasing my eclipse Memory from 512 to 1024.