# Android 5.0 IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: on com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-api, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to retrieve the location of the device calling the method *connect* of the class *LocationClient* in my activity, however when the call is made the system crashes with the following exception:

```
**FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.unipagossales, PID: 3833
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unipagossales/com.unipagossales.app.merchants.MerchantFragmentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START }
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START }
    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.v.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.unipagossales.app.merchants.MerchantFragmentActivity.onStart(MerchantFragmentActivity.java:122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    ... 10 more
**
```

This is the way I create my LocationClient:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.merchant_activity);

    ...

    // Create a new global location parameters object
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_MILLISECONDS);

    // Initialize the location client
    locationClient = new LocationClient(this, new LocationClientConnectionCallbacks(), new LocationClientOnConnectionFailedListener());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ...
    locationClient.connect();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to the fact that Android VM is not being able in runtime to find the definition of the action `act=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START` in Google Play Services.

You will need to set your Google Play Services following the next blog:

http://mflerackers.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/noclassdeffounderror-for-googleplayservicesutil/

Then you will need to increment the VM values in eclipse.ini, follow this one:

[Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

This should fix your exception collaterally.

Comment: Excellent, this was a saver!

Answer (score 3):

Changing the target SDK version to "19" helped me.

Comment: Even if we use the old google play library and if the target SDK version is 21, application will crash.

Comment: Sudheesh did you figure it out or do you still have trouble?