# android: eclipse stuck on launching application

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm developing an android application, which worked well until yesterday when I started to add a MapView. Launching the application (on a real device) results n Eclipse to get stuck on "launching : 100%" and after a while it dies with the attached error and I have to close the IDE.

[image: error]

It turned out the problem is the google Play services library project, if I remove the dependency pointing to it from my application, the whole thing start to work again, but of course I can't use maps.

any solution?

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit `eclipse.ini` inside your eclipse folder

```
    openFile
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    512M
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    512m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -Xms512m
    -Xmx1024m
```

from this answer -[Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: thank you....I never had this error before.....strange...