# Errors in launching an android application

Tags: java, android, memory, heap-memory

I am trying to run an android application and I get the following error

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed. Unable to execute dex: Java heap space Java heap space

Any suggestions

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space)

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to Dalvik format failed.

occures when there are some problem in build path 
check your application build path there may be some unwanted things imported remove them.
hope it will help you