# Android: trying to import a project and keep getteing Unable to execute dex:error

Tags: android

I imported a android project and it seemed like everything worked (I can see all the files in the project).
When I try to run it I get the following error
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Java heap space

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [@JohnnyLambada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9648/johnnylambada) in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space) try to

Modify the `-XmsAm` and `-XmxBm` paremeters in `eclipse.ini` so that they are large enough. The default is `-Xms40m` `-Xmx384m`. Try changing them both to `-Xms512m` `-Xmx512m` and restart eclipse to see if that helps. If not, continue to increase the values and restart eclipse until either one of two things happens:

Your build completes.
Eclipse won't restart because you don't have enough memory.
eclipse.ini is located at `/etc/eclipse.ini` in Ubuntu (assuming you installed Eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories) or search where you put your eclipse For Windows.