# Eclipse Java heap space

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to integrate qoppa pdf reader to my android application

I did like it was described here:
http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/guide/index.html
- add jar file into classpath of my project.
- add assets folder.
- add libs folder.

When I start Eclipse, everything works fine, I can open the projects in my workspace and continue implementing. But when running the pdf project as a new Eclipse instance, i get this error

```
    [2012-10-29 22:23:25 - com.test] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(c.b.b.c.b.b.b.b.b.i$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-10-29 22:26:21 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
[2012-10-29 22:26:23 - com.test] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

I tryed clean my project, but still getting the error.

I searched in the net, so i found that  I have to increased the PermGen size in the eclipse.ini file and in the Run Configuration. 
Here are my evlipse.ini after some changes:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

No use, I still get the error.

What could be the problem?

i Think it is because of qoppapdf.jar, the size of the jar is huge, more than 4000000 bytes.
But it is supposed to work because there are samples using this jar, i don't know why my eclipse can't do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the allocated memory for your running configuration, not for eclipse. 
Add the -Xms256m and -Xms1024m under VM arguments field.

[image]

Comment: how did you get this view, in my eclipse when i choose "run configuration", i only get thre tabs (android, target, common). There are no arguments

Comment: @haythemsouissi I'm sorry, this was a 'Run configuration' editor for a plain java project not an android one :(.

Comment: @haythemsouissi See this link for details on how to increase the eclipse memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space Your question is a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
-> Right click your project. 
-> Go to Properties 
-> Java Build Path 
-> Order and Export.
-> Uncheck the check box against your included library. 
-> Press OK and run the project.
```

On doing this Eclipse will take only the classes which are needed in the code, from the jar instead of storing all the classes from the jar.

Answer (score 1):

change the -Xms256m to -Xms1024m as well, its only giving it 256 megs, java apps are memory intensive and need a lot.