# Android: Deploy freezes (Java heap Space)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, heap-memory

Today I tried to deploy my android app from my mac to a usb connected device. It has always worked but today eclipse frooze and returned;

```
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Java heap space
```

After a couple minutes.

My eclipse.ini has these memory properties:

`-XX:MaxPermSize=1536m -Xms40m -Xmx1536m`

Isn't this enough? And yeah my RAM is 8GB running Mountain Lion.

Cheers!

Comment: the `MaxPermSize` doesn't need to be that large, smaller (I have it at 256m) seems to work better for me. Try increasing the Xmx to like 4096m since that is the heap limit

Comment: I think that error "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space" is not related to eclipse, but the application. You can try put the value in VM arguments (Run -> Run Configuration ->  Arguments) to stop this error.

Comment: @matheuslf I cannot find that

Comment: Below the option Search you have to click the arrow responsible for running the application. Find the option Run Configuration, click in your application -> Arguments.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space increasing eclipse heap is the solution

Comment: @matheuslf Sorry it does not working