# Eclipse hang after import google play library

Tags: eclipse, google-maps, freeze

I've import `google play service library` in one of my app and now my eclipse hang and go out of memory when I try to run only this app.
There aren't error messege before launch and I've just tried few time but without success.

Eclipse show me this message:

```
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

After increasing memory in *eclipse.ini* as is indicated in various posts, I obtain this new error:

```
Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Here my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Can someone help me?
I've no idea how solve this issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to edit the `-XmsAm` and `-XmxBm` parameters manually from the `eclipse.ini` file to increase memory. Here try this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024262/2896954

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I've editi this line --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m and increase it to 1024m and now work. I can't see the lines that you have mentioned, do you think that it's better add them to my ecplipse.ini? Now all works...