# Adding Google Maps to Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am developing an Android App with Eclipse and the Android SDK on my mac and everything works fine. I am debugging on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

And I got the problem, that as soon as I add google-play-services_lib as library to my Android project and try to debug it again, my Eclipse uses every percent of my processor it gets and gets slower and slower till it freezes. I have to kill it on the commandline, otherwise it remains in this state and I can not work on.

Anyone faced the same problem? I could really need some help, because I don't know, how to solve that problem.

Kind regards

rholtermann

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to use Eclipse instead of Android Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581820/eclipse-hang-after-import-google-play-library

Comment: to Arkadiy: no, there is no particular reason, I just had eclipse installed and I use it for other projects, maybe I should give Android Studio a try.

Comment: to kaho: thanks for your link, I don't know why I didn't see it, before I asked this question. increasing the limits solved the problem.