# google-play-services_lib Android on Eclipse infinite launching

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a problem using `google-play-services_lib` on Android.

I followed this tutorial. [Getting the Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)
to import it on eclipse, but when I add in my project reference Google Play services library and I try to run it on my Nexus 5, Eclipse starts an infinite launching and I must kill it.

I update all in SDK manager. What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you may try use Android Studio, it's easy.http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space

Comment: @bjiang I followed that guide to configure Play Services with Eclipse + ADT.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when their is a lot of XML (layout) on the activity and the memory is not sufficient to hold the elements all together. In that case the Eclipse hangs and if you run it again all the launching gets queued up, the ultimate solution is to kill all the launch manually to get it restarted. Although Eclipse is lightweighted it is poor in memory management for android. Using Android Studio is a better solution.

Is their anything you are getting in your logcat?