# I am trying for implementing gmail login but it shows an error "unable to execute dex: java heap space eclipse"

Tags: android, eclipse, gmail, heap-memory

Unable to implement Gmail Login in eclipse ubuntu 14.04
I have imported Google play sevice library also but when i am executing it shows error "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space" and "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space"

Thanks in advance

Comment: refer this you need to update your eclipse.ini file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space

Comment: Hi wishy thanks for reply but I tried  it didn't help me.