# how to solve error Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space when aspose-pdf-10.4.1.jar is in lib folder

Tags: eclipse, pdf, aspose

I just added `aspose-pdf-10.4.1.jar` to `libs` folder of my project in eclipse. And some codes in one of my buttons click event. And when i want to run this project the error `Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space` occur. After this i am using `android:largeHeap="true"` and increased value of `xmx` and `xms` in `eclipse.ini` file. but still i have that problem. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space)

Comment: I have increased size of xmx and xms both to 512 but now i see Launching myapp(100%) in the right down corner of eclipse.

Comment: @Josua Schmid:one thing that happened is that i removed the myjar file(29MB size) from lib folder. and eclipse run app with no Problem. but when i add it again to lib folder i must wait and do not know when eclipse installs app in the phone.

Comment: @JosuaSchmid i added my jar file through external jar and can run application but when i want to use it in my button click an error occured. error is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aspose.pdf.Document

Comment: Hi Karim, My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose. Please note that recently we have also noticed some compatibility issues of Aspose.Pdf for Android with Eclipse IDE. Therefore we recommend using Google Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @codewarior: Hi Nayyer. thank you for your comment. i will migrate to that  in future.